# local variable 'menu_actions' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I keep getting this error regardless of what I try to do to fix it. I have used this method in another script i made and it worked perfectly but for some reason it just isnt working with this one. The idea is to go back to the first menu number 2 is selected. Please note i did check the other related posts but they didnt help me at all.

```
import os
import sys

def menu():
    print  """

this is a test menu

"""
menu()

def back(): 
    menu_actions['menu']()

    menu_actions = {
         'menu': menu,
         '2': back,
         }

choice = raw_input(">>")
if choice == '2':
    back()
```

Comment: Your `menu_actions` assignment appears after your use of it in your method `back()`. Perhaps the `menu_actions=` should not be inside the `back()` method, i.e, should not be indented.

Comment: try moving the `menu_actions` dictionary outside of the scope of the `back` function (i.e. below the `back` function just before you are defining `choice`.

Comment: That worked but it wont allow me to choose an option a second time. It loops and then exits the script.

Comment: Oh, didn't realize that is what you were trying to accomplish. In that case you probably need a while loop so that the program continues to loop until you `control-c` or otherwise purposefully exit. Does that sound like an accurate of what you are looking to accomplish?

Comment: Yes it does. I will try that

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Ok, feel free to close question or I will delete my answer. Glad you got it resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def menu():
    print  """

this is a test menu

"""

def back(): 
    menu_actions['menu']()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    menu_actions = {
       'menu': menu,
       '2': back,
    }

    menu()

    while True:
        choice = raw_input(">>")
        if choice == '2':
            back()
```

As explained in the comments by both @John Anderson and myself, the menu_actions dictionary is being referenced before it is defined, which is why you are running in to that error.

Once this is moved outside the scope of the `back` function it will work fine. Though if you want the program to continue running after returning to the main menu then the entire program needs to be running inside an infinite loop, and it would only terminate when you needed it to. You could always add additional error handling to error at other times too once your program gets more complex!

Hope this helps solve your problem.